# How to "tail" multiple pipe files or streams?

Tags: pipe, tail, named-pipe

I need to monitor a lot of web servers for runtime errors and I have an idea of running a script like

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# Example set of hosts
HOSTS=(
host1
host2
)

for host in ${HOSTS[@]}
do
        [[ ! -e ${host}.pipe ]] && mkfifo ${host}.pipe
        (ssh -n $host "tail -n0 -F /tmp/test" >> ${host}.pipe) &
done

tail -F -c +0 *.pipe
```

and it would supposedly give me such output:

```
==> host1.pipe <==
event 1
event 2

==> host2.pipe <==
event 3
event 4

==> host1.pipe <==
event 5
```

You get the point. I see log lines as they appear, with their origin being obvious from how `tail -F` shows it usually when you run on more than one file.

Tail options `-c +0` supposedly makes it print stream contents starting from 0th byte.

But this doesn't work! What I see is like

```
==> host1.pipe <==
event 1
event 2
event 5
```

That is, no stream except first is shown.

Here's simpler variation of above script, still reproducing the issue:

```
tail -F -c +0 \
        <(ssh host1 "tail -n1 -F /tmp/test") \
        <(ssh host2 "tail -n1 -F /tmp/test") \
        ;
```

Even simpler, still reproducing the issue:

```
tail -F -c +0 \
    <(while true; do date;     sleep 1; done) \
    <(while true; do date +%s; sleep 1; done)
```

I'm using tail from coreutils 8.27 and Linux kernel 4.9.14.

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Note that I won't like to be suggested to use "multitail". I've tried it, splitting screen in panes won't scale to dozens of servers which we have now.

Comment: One guy on coreutils maillist has confirmed the issue and is thinking on a patch to allow my usecase: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/coreutils/2017-09/msg00021.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that I won't like to be suggested to use `multitail`. I've tried it, splitting screen in panes won't scale to dozens of servers which we have now.

How about `-L` option? It doesn't split screen.

```
multitail \
  --mark-change \
  -L "while sleep 1; do date;     done" \
  -L "while sleep 5; do date +%s; done" \
  -L "while sleep 7; do date +%Y; done"
```

If you want to use named pipes you should use `-I` instead of `-L`. Unfortunatelly `multitail` requires separate `-I` for every file, this makes the wildcard (`*`) approach more difficult. Bad luck, its `-Iw` option doesn't seem to work with named pipes; and I couldn't make the tool cooperate with `xargs` (at least on my Debian).

Still there is a way:

```
multitail --mark-change --mergeall *.pipe
```

The output will be very similar to what you expected from `tail`.

Comment: Thanks, modes you suggested indeed deliver what I want (tested just first mode at the moment).

However, I find ncurses interface a bit limiting. It has its own scrollback buffer while I'd like my terminal to take care of it; has a bit strange scrollback access.

If I don't get an answer for original "tail" (which has a bug as I guess), I will mark your answer as chosen.

Thanks a lot anyway, your help is highly appreciated.